# Sharing sample apps across devices

Tags: android

Let say that I already have a working prototype of an app. How can I share that working prototype with other device without directly plugging the device to the source code in android studio?.

Comment: compile a release apk using Android Studio, then transfer that file over to the device. then try to open it using a file manager app - you'll be prompted to install - you will also need to check "Unknown Sources" in security settings if its not enabled already.

Answer (score 2):

The app is compiled into an APK file. You can share this with other people any way you wish: email, download from a website, etc. Be sure you share the release version of your APK, not the debug version. You can also create a developer account on Google Play and upload your app there. If you are not ready for a public release, you can create Alpha and Beta releases instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is several where i can think of is:

1. Create an API for development application where this API is called
   on splashscreen OR background service. This API work as function
   checker to check is there is new version of APK exist in server. If exist, app will popup the user to download new apk by given link from the API.
2. Ask the user to register the beta testing in GooglePlay
3. Upload on google drive and share the link to user
4. Finally, Send email of the APK to user by subject of version